Firebase cloud function to respond within 3 seconds but continue running
I have a Streamchat webhook that triggers a Firebase Cloud Function everytime a chat is sent. The webhook expects a response within 3 seconds but my logic takes longer than that to run. How can I make my cloud function close the webhook within the 3 seconds and continue running? The function is also taking a long time to actually send the response message to the chat.
export const chatBot = onRequest(
  { timeoutSeconds: 15, region: ["europe-west2"], maxInstances: 5 },
  async (request, response) => {
    try {
      if (request.body.user.id !== "system-user") {
        //I thought this would close the webhook before continuing to run the function
        response.status(200);
        const client = StreamChat.getInstance("abc", "abc123");
        const signature = request.headers["x-signature"] as string;
        const valid = client.verifyWebhook(request.rawBody, signature);
        if (!valid) {
          return;
        } else {
          const channel = client.channel(
            request?.body?.channel?.type,
            request?.body?.channel?.id
          );
          const messageHistory = new FirestoreChatMessageHistory({
            collections: ["users", "chats"],
            docs: [request.body.user.id, request.body.channel.name],
            sessionId: request.body.user.id,
            userId: request.body.user.id,
            config: {
              projectId: "xyz",
              credential: admin.credential.cert({
                projectId: "xyz",
                privateKey:
                  "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
                clientEmail: "firebase-adminsdk@xyz.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
              }),
            },
          });

          const llm = new ChatOpenAI({
            modelName: "gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
            temperature: 0,
            openAIApiKey: "abc123",
          });

          const prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages([
            ["system", "You are a helpful assistant"],
            new MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history"),
            ["user", "{input}"],
            new MessagesPlaceholder("agent_scratchpad"),
          ]);

          const tools = [
            new DynamicTool({
              name: "date-time",
              description:
                "Call this to get the date and time right now. Input should be an empty string.",
              func: async () => new Date(Date.now()).toString(),
            }),
          ];

          const agent = await createOpenAIToolsAgent({
            llm,
            tools,
            prompt,
          });

          const agentExecutor = new AgentExecutor({
            agent,
            tools,
          });

          const conversationalAgentExecutor = new RunnableWithMessageHistory({
            runnable: agentExecutor,
            getMessageHistory: (_sessionId) => messageHistory,
            inputMessagesKey: "input",
            outputMessagesKey: "output",
            historyMessagesKey: "chat_history",
          });

          const chatBotRes = await conversationalAgentExecutor.invoke(
            {
              input: request.body.message.text,
            },
            {
              configurable: {
                sessionId: request?.body?.user?.id,
              },
            }
          );
          await channel.sendMessage({
            user_id: "system-user",
            text: chatBotRes.output,
          });
        }
      }
      response.status(200).end();
      return;
    } catch (err) {
      logger.info(err);
      response.status(200).end();
      return;
    }
  }
);

Is there something wrong? I keep getting an axios timeout error. Despite the timeout error, it still works but I don't know if it causes any performance issues or if this is why it's taking so long for the message to be sent back. The chatbot response takes about 3 minutes to be sent to the chat. Thank you for your help!

You should add some logging in your code to benchmark each part of the function to find out how long each takes and which ones are taking the most time.  We can't tell from looking at your code what those might be.  Also consider that cloud functions have a built-in cold start time that you can't control other than by configuring a minimum number of instances.

Just to clarify, res.status(200) sends a response back to the webhook but it wouldn't terminate the execution of the cloud function, right? The fact my function has a 15s timeout also means it won't run for longer than that, so the 3 minutes that the reply takes to be displayed could be on StreamChat's end?

No, sending any response will terminate the function.  This is documented behavior.  You can't make a function continue execution in the "background" for any amount of time.
